# Splitting all lines in layer at vertices using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, line, splitting, vertices

I want to automatically split all lines in a QGIS layer at their vertices ([like this](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Split_Line_At_Vertices_%28Data_Management%29)).

I've done a Google search and found [this article](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2010-September/009635.html), which is quite close but the workflow is complicated. Because I'll have to train my co-workers (who are unfamiliar with GIS) to use this tool, I want something as simple as a plugin or something that doesn't require GRASS.

Since it's been a long time from 2010 - the time of [the previous answer](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2010-September/009635.html), I wonder if there is any better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: You can use GRASS tools from QGIS nowdays.Maybe Vector->Geometry Tools->Single parts to multipart could help. Sextante toolbox should have "Explode line layer" And there is plugin "split feature"

Comment: I think that the answer you referred to is (still) the correct procedure. The vector tool "Single Part to Multipart" will not do what you want. It splits a multi-linestring at the *nodes*, not at each vertex.

Comment: @simplexio: with Sextante toolbox, I received an error message as in Bernd V. answer and I can't find the 'split feature' plugin anywhere on the net.

Comment: @Micha: that procedure may be correct but it will be too complex for my fellow co-workers - who are unfamiliar with GIS, so I'll consider it as the last resort, when all else failed :)

Comment: @Cao Minh Tu: i tested 'Split feature' again on Linux Master and on Win7 1.8 with a newly created line layer, and there it works. Please create a test layer from scratch and apply it there. Maybe there are errors in your original layers which have to be resolved first !?

Comment: @BerndV.: 'Split Feature' works well when the source layer is a shapefile but returns an empty layer when the source is in spatialite (as in my previous case). Your answer marked as accepted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try the ["Explode lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#explode-lines) from the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) will split all lines at their vertices to separate lines.

Menu Processing -> Toolbox. Type "explode" into the search field to find the function. Select your line layer from the dropdown and start. This will produce a new layer.

Selecting one or more lines from the line layer will produce a splitted layer with only these features, discarding the rest.

**Note:** As QGIS is moving fast, all infos below are outdated already.

> I think **Explode lines** would be the the noob-solution through the
> **SEXTANTE toolbox**.  `QGIS Geoalgorithms > Vector geometry tools > Explode lines`. Unfortunately, it does not seem to work at the moment,
> i get an error message only.
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "path/.qgis//python/plugins\sextante\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 145, in execute
>     self.processAlgorithm(progress)
>   File "path/.qgis//python/plugins\sextante\algs\Explode.py", line 58, in processAlgorithm
>     features = QGisLayers.features(layer)
> NameError: global name 'layer' is not defined
> ```
>
> A working solution is the `Split Feature`-Plugin from the
> "contributed" repository, which does the job for me.
>
> In general I prefer sextante functions over separate plugins, cause
> the workflow with sextante is so much faster and produces no
> junk-files of intermediate steps (provided it works).
>
> **EDIT:** Unfortunately, a lot of plugins were not moved to the official plugin repository yet, but are still only available through
> the "contributed" plugin repository:
> http://pyqgis.org/repo/contributed, which was removed from the default
> repositories list with version 1.8.
>
> There you can download them individually and unzip them in your
> .qgis/python/plugins folder OR you add this address to your plugins
> repository list: `Plugins -> Fetch python plugins -> Tab "Repositories" -> Add ... -> enter a name and the url.`

Comment: Can you tell me where to find the 'Split Feature' plugin - I can't find it in the official plugin repository? With SEXTANTE Explode lines, I received the same error message as yours - there's a bug report here: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7157

Comment: @Cao Minh Tu: sorry, completely forgot that i added the old repository to my list, where this plugin resides exclusivly. see my edits.

Comment: I tried the Split Feature plugin, there's no error message but the output layer contained nothing.

Comment: There is only a 404 error at http://pyqgis.org/repo/contributed - has the URL changed?

Comment: @til_be see my edit

Comment: this one removing z values from the exported shape file.

Comment: @TamasKosa Never worked with z-values in shapes. I think they are still a weak point in QGIS. Did you try to use another format like SpatiaLite or Geopackage for the output? Maybe its worth a bug report in https://issues.qgis.org/issues/ ?

Comment: @BerndV. the GRASS solution below, keeps the Z value. We've tested it, hope it helps to others as well.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open/Create GRASS mapset (so you can run the tools on your data)
2. Open GRASS tools / Import the shapefile you want to split into the GRASS database
3. Run v.split.vert (set maximum number of vertices = 2)

Comment: This solution keeps z values in the segment geometries

Answer (score 1):

```py
lines = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layer_name')[0]

segment_list = []

for feature in lines.getFeatures():
    vertices = feature.geometry().asPolyline() # returns list of vertices comprising polyline
    for point in range(len(vertices)-1):
        segment = QgsFeature()
        segment.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(vertices[point]), QgsPoint(vertices [point+1])]))
        segment.setAttributes(feature.attributes())
        segment_list.append(segment.geometry())
        
print(segment_list)
```