# Split OSM highways at vertice

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2po

I am looking for a tool or query to split the OSM highways into multiple segments. Each segment should only consist of two nodes (start and end).

I should do the same as described in [this GIS Stackexchange answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54933/simple-automated-way-to-split-all-lines-in-layer-at-vertices-using-qgis) but with PostGIS.

Is there an importing tool like osm2po that I can do this with?
Note I don't only want to split it at intersections.

Or alternatively, how could I use `ST_Split()` or `ST_Dump()` to do this?

Comment: See if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595635/how-to-convert-polygon-data-into-line-segments-using-postgis

Answer (score 2):

You are going to split at each point? This may produce tons of data!

Yes, **osm2po** can do that. Usually osm2po splits at intersections or at important nodes such as levelcrossings if necessary. The trick is, to give these nodes an *importance*. Namely, by setting the `Node-Clazz >0`. A good example of how to do it you'll find inside the plugins-source-zip. Look for TrafficSignals. In your case every node seems important, so just remove the condition.

Comment: Yes I want to split it at each point. I will only do this for a small extract, so I am not to concerned about the data volume. Can you point out a little further where exactly I have to set the `Node-Clazz` or where exactly inside the plugins-source-zip I can find an example?

Comment: Are you familiar with Java? If not, try to convert the created road segments with PostGIS means.