# QGIS object selecting if any segment length is longer than

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, select, length

I have a polygon layer with generated triangles covering for example district or city area. I need to select all the triangles if any triangle (object) segment is longer than 100 meters. Picture: selected triangles has a that segment (or many segments)
[image]

I prefer not to explode triangles to lines, calculating length and selecting lines, and run spatial query with triangles because every exploded line may touch a triangles with shorter segments.

Tnx. Tomek

Answer (score 3):

You could use the **[Explode Lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54933/simple-automated-way-to-split-all-lines-in-layer-at-vertices-using-qgis)** algorithm in the Processing Toolbox and then in the result table add a virtual field calculating the length of each object (=segment) ...

Comment: I prefer not to explode triangles to lines, calculating length and selecting lines, and run spatial query with triangles because every exploded line may touch a triangles with shorter segments. Tnx. Tomek

Comment: sorry ... but i don't understand why the exploded lines touching the triangles may affect the result ... (they are in another table)