# Exploding line into segments using QGIS

Tags: qgis, linestring, vertices, polyline-creation, geometry-conversion

Is there a command to explode a line feature (with many segments) into its segments?

Like this:
[image]

I have seen this: [Splitting all lines in layer at vertices using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54933/simple-automated-way-to-split-all-lines-in-layer-at-vertices-using-qgis)

But, I was looking for something similar that keeps everything in the same layer while editing it and does it only for the selected feature(s) not all elements. I am thinking in a simple command that takes the selected featured(s) and produces the desired output like the `Split Parts` or `Split Features` in the `Advanced Digitizing Toolbar`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tool therefore is called ["Explode lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#explode-lines) and can be found in the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) in `Vector geometry` tools. It takes all lines and breaks them into its segments into a new layer.

In order to get a new number for each segment an update can be performed on the `"id"` field in the Field Calculator using `@row_number`.