# Selecting single line after polygon is split into line segments

Tags: qgis-3, linestring, polyline-creation, geometry-conversion

In QGIS 3.20 on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit I have used the menu sequence `Vector/Geometry Tools/Polygons to lines` to create a new line layer from a polygon layer which contains several polygons.

However I notice that the attribute table for the new line layer seems to have only a single feature for each of the former polygons, and when I try to select a single line on the canvas, I get all the lines from the original polygon. So I cannot delete just one side of the original polygon which was the reason I did the conversion. What more must I do?

Comment: Try Multipart to singlepart processing tool

Comment: Ran the Multipart to Singlepart but still only one feature in the attribute table for each former polygon.  Selection gets the whole polygon still.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO just one extra step left, which is described in [Splitting all lines in layer at vertices using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54933/splitting-all-lines-in-layer-at-vertices-using-qgis).

As was mentioned by @BERA the application of ["Multipart to singleparts"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) can also bring its benefits (if original polygon features are multi-part).

Comment: Did that.  Still the same - one feature in the new attribute table for each former polygon and selection gets whole polygon.

Comment: Can you share your data/piece of data with us?

Comment: I've tried to find out how I can do this as it seems that file uploads are not allowed.  What is alternative?

Comment: Dropbox or WeTransfer